# How to get yabai to recognize zathura pdf viewer

Tags: applications, window-manager

I have been trying to switch to [zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) from [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) but whenever I launch Zathura, [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) doesn't recognize and tile it like other windows, is there a way to fix this?

For those not familiar with the apps mentioned above:

- [zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) is a highly customizable and functional document viewer
- [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) is a PDF reader and note-taker for macOS
- [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai) is a tiling window management for the Mac

Comment: Have you contacted the developers of yaba and Zathurai, or looked on their websites for any updates?